# Pandasでカラム名がどうしても小文字で出力される際の対処

Tags: python, pandas

pandasのデータフレームdfで最終id、という名前のカラムがあり、
`df.rename(columns = {'最終id':'最終ID'})`
とリネームしても出力物では小文字のidに戻ってしまいます。
どのようにすれば回避できますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

**実行環境**
Windows 10
Python 3.7

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) を参照しますと、`inplace=True` を付けるか、`df = df.rename(columns = {'最終id':'最終ID'})` とする必要があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
そこはクリアできていたと思いますが、もう一度確認します。（できていなかったらすいません。。）

Comment: 確認した結果、`df=df.rename`で解決しました。こちらの手違いだったようです。
すいませんでした。